# How to read a text file in Java into an array

Tags: java

How to read a text file in Java like the following:
6 - is the total number of elements, this is placed on the first line
5 1 6 3 2 - this are the array numbers, this is placed on the second line

I've tried using scanner, using the delimiter but all the time I get an exception on the first line, Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

So the 6 is the total number of elements and the nextline is the array of elements. I want to implememnt on this an algorithm that will find the missing number(4 in our case). But my question si about how to read the file, not how to implement the algorithm..

This is the code:

```
List<Integer> temps = new ArrayList<>();

        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("fisier.txt")))) {
            scanner.useDelimiter(" ");
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                int number = scanner.nextInt();
                scanner.nextLine();
                int data = scanner.nextInt();
                scanner.skip(scanner.delimiter());
                temps.add(number);
                temps.add(data);
            }

            Integer[] tempsArray = temps.toArray(new Integer[0]);
            for (Integer s : tempsArray) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }



        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Please add the code where you get the InputMismatchException

Comment: I've just added the code !

Comment: You're reading **two numbers each time around** your `while` loop.  Does that make any sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader br;
FileInputStream fin;

try {
    fin = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));

    // Read and Split a line.
    String line = br.readLine().trim();
    String[] attributes = line.split(" ");

    // cast to int and get values
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String attribute : attributes) {
        numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(attribute);
    }

    // Sort it ascending
    Collections.sort(numbers);

    // algorithm to find missing one
    // first+last one can´t be wrong so it´s working
    int checkValue = numbers.get(0);
    int missing;
    for(Int number : numbers) {
        if(checkvalue != number) {
            missing = checkValue;
            break;
        }
        checkValue++;
    }

    System.out.println("Missing Number: " + missing):

    fin.close();
    br.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.err.println("Your Message");
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Your Message");
}
```

Comment: Add your loop for each line if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

This will read the file line by line into an array list for loop through that an parse the number. You could use Apache commons IO to do `FileUtils.downloadToFile`

```
List<String> data = new ArrayList<>;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(new File("data.txt")));
String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
     data.add(line);
br.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

for some reason nextInt() dont like text file, i have solved it using method `scanner.hasNext()` for control and `Integer.valueOf(scanner.next())` to return an int value.

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    if(scanner.hasNext());
       int number = Integer.valueOf(scanner.next());
    scanner.nextLine();
    if(scanner.hasNext());                  
        int data = Integer.valueOf(scanner.next());
    scanner.skip(scanner.delimiter());
    temps.add(number);
    temps.add(data);
}
```

be sure your file contains only castable to int values, you can make a control like :

```
String dataS = scanner.next();
if(StringUtils.isNumeric(String dataS))
     int data = Integer.valueOf(dataS);
```

when `StringUtils.isNumeric()` is from **Apache Commons**